# Speed up simple distance calculation

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, numpy, distance

I'm implementing a simple code that calculates the distance between a point `(x_a, y_a)` in `list_A` and all points `(x_b, y_b)` in `list_B` and returns the minimum distance found. This is repeated for all points in `list_A`.

A `MWE` of my code:

```
# list_A points defined in array.
list_A = np.array([
    [x_data_a,  # x
     y_data_a]  # y
    ], dtype=float)

# list_B points defined in list.
list_B = [[x_data_b], [y_data_b]]

# Iterate through all data points in list_A
for ind, x_a in enumerate(list_A[0][0]):
    y_a = list_A[0][1][ind]

    # Iterate through all points in list_B.
    dist_min = 1000.
    for ind2, x_b in enumerate(list_B[0]):
        y_b = list_B[1][ind2]
        # Find distance between points.
        dist = (x_a-x_b)**2 + (y_a-y_b)**2
        if dist < dist_min:
            # Update value of min distance.
            dist_min = dist

    print 'Min dist to (', x_a, y_a, '): ', dist_min
```

The data is formatted like this:

```
list_A = [[[1.2 2.3 1.5 2.3 5.8 4.6 9.1] [2.5 1.0 4.6 2.4 7.4 1.1 3.2]]]

list_B = [[1.4, 5.8, 7.9], [6.1, 1.2, 3.7]]
```

For big lists/arrays this can take quite some time to finish. Can this be sped up?

Comment: Based on your comments on some of the answers, I realize I don't understand the format of your data.  Are you saying that `x_data_a` is itself a sequence of points?  Can you provide a simple example of your data structure with literal numerical values?

Comment: Please see edited question. I think using `zip` might do the trick because I'm getting a `ValueError: XA and XB must have the same number of columns (i.e. feature dimension.)` error.

Comment: Your example still doesn't make sense.  I don't see any points there, just lists of individual numbers.  You can't have `...` inside your individual points, because then you wouldn't know the dimension of the points and can't find distances between them.  Please provide a small literal example without `...`.

Comment: Sorry, the `...` where to shorten the list. I've updated que question showing how a real set of data would look like. In any case, I'm pretty sure using `zip(*)` is the solution to the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, your arrays are formatted the wrong way around, and you can use `zip(*list_A)` to get them into the right format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your code I obtain the following:

```
Min dist to ( 1.2 2.5 ):  13.0
Min dist to ( 2.3 1.0 ):  12.29
Min dist to ( 1.5 4.6 ):  2.26
Min dist to ( 2.3 2.4 ):  13.69
Min dist to ( 5.8 7.4 ):  18.1
Min dist to ( 4.6 1.1 ):  1.45
Min dist to ( 9.1 3.2 ):  1.69
```

Converting your array to the following Nx2 arrays:

```
a
[[ 1.2  2.5]
 [ 2.3  1. ]
 [ 1.5  4.6]
 [ 2.3  2.4]
 [ 5.8  7.4]
 [ 4.6  1.1]
 [ 9.1  3.2]]

b
[[ 1.4  6.1]
 [ 5.8  1.2]
 [ 7.9  3.7]]
```

Now the following should work:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as spdist

dist_arr = spdist.cdist(a,b)

print dist_arr**2
[[ 13.    22.85  46.33]
 [ 26.82  12.29  38.65]
 [  2.26  30.05  41.77]
 [ 14.5   13.69  33.05]
 [ 21.05  38.44  18.1 ]
 [ 35.24   1.45  17.65]
 [ 67.7   14.89   1.69]]

ind = np.argmin(dist_arr,axis=1)

print ind
[0 1 0 1 2 1 2]

print dist_arr[np.arange(ind.shape[0]),ind]**2
[ 13.    12.29   2.26  13.69  18.1    1.45   1.69]
```

Takes ~.3 seconds if `a` and `b` are 2X5000 vs ~135 seconds with the original code. A speedup of 450 times.

Comment: Please see the question I made above in BrenBarn's answer regarding the dimensions of the input lists. Also, why did you choose this particular disposition of elements? My setup is two sub-lists in each parent list (A and B), containing x and y values and the total number of x,y pairs is not necessarily the same in A and B.

Comment: @Gabriel: His example already shows this working with different lengths in the input lists, as I explained in my comment on my answer.

Comment: @Gabriel I have replicated your results using `cdist` for a ~400x speedup over the original code.

Comment: @Ophion I got similar results although not as faster as what you found (I found a ~40x speedup but I mixed the answer with some more code) Thank for all the answers guys! I'm marking this one as accepted because it has some more detail than BrenBarn's answer, even though they are both based on `cdist`. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) and you don't need to write your own distance-calculation code at all.

Edit: You need to transpose your data.  It should be in a format like this:

```
list_A = [
 [1, 2],
 [3, 4],
 [4, 5]
]

list_B = [
 [8, 9],
 [10, 11],
 [11, 12],
 [13, 14]
]
```

Currently what you have is a list of X coordinates and a separate list of Y coordinates.  You need to reorient these so you have a single list of XY pairs.  If your data are ordinary lists you can transpose them with `list_A = zip(*list_A)`; if they are numpy arrays you can transpose them with `list_A = list_A.T`.

Comment: Wouldn't using this require `x_data_a` and `x_data_b` to have the same length (same for y values)? Because that is not a restriction I can impose on my data.

Comment: @Gabriel: No, if I understand you right.  If you have one list of M points and another list of N points, you can use `cdist` to find all distances from every point in M to every point in N.  The two lists don't have to have equal length.  (The points you're finding the distance between do have to have the same number of components --- that is, the same dimension --- but if you want to find all distances you need that no matter what.)

Comment: @Gabriel: I see your format now.  You need to transpose it so you have lists of XY pairs, not separate lists of X and Y coordinates.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using scipy to get scipy.spatial.dist

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(2,1000) 
b = np.random.rand(2,1001)

min_dist = np.sqrt(np.min([np.min(np.sum((b - a[:,i,None])**2, axis=0)) 
                           for i in range(a.shape[1])]))
```

If you're looking for min dist for each point in a, then replace the last line with

```
min_dists = np.sqrt([np.min(np.sum((b - a[:,i,None])**2, axis=0)) 
                           for i in range(a.shape[1])])
```

Comment: For time gain, you can avoid `np.sqrt` and use `np.argmin` instead of `np.min` then you point into the index of the value. Next you just have to return value[index]. (np.sqrt time gained)

Comment: @Katsu He wants the minimum distance found, so I have to do the sqrt at some point and it's only called once.  Maybe I'm not understanding you.

Comment: It's only called on float not a list yes, sorry. You can use xrange instead of range it's better here with iterator.

Comment: Alternatively you can simply do this `np.sqrt(np.min(np.sum((a[:,None,:]-b[:,:,None])**2,axis=0)))`, there is no need for looping here, but this only gives a singular value. I believe he is looking for multiple.

Comment: @Ophion I thought of that (I love python broadcasting!), but was worried about the memory requirement.  For my example, a[:,None,:]-b[:,:,None] creates a 2 x 1001 x 1000 array.